# Asset Library: Catalogues show, but not Marked Assets

Tags: asset-browser

Short description of problem:

- Briefly got Asset Library working, re-organized files under new sub folders.
- Suddenly new and old blend files no longer see any marked assets, only the catalogues.
- I have unmarked/marked the assets, added them to new Asset Libraries several times over
- I deleted catalogue files in the directory hoping forcing them to repopulate would fix it
- All blender files are now using the same File Path and Asset Library
- All assets are marked within their .blend file and show under the Library not just main file
- Attached screenshots

Blender Version:
3.3.1

Asset Library Location:
W:\My Blender Assets\

My Example Asset Location:
W:\My Blender Assets\Characters\Human Base Blockout

Any help would be appreciated, the Blender Documentation and every youtube video I watch acts like this is a flawless system. This is not the first bug I encountered setting this up today, but is the one that has me on the brink of giving up.

Unreal has a perfectly functioning asset browser, I just wanted my workflow to be in one spot...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on "All blender files are now using the same File Path and Asset Library" and "I deleted catalogue files in the directory hoping forcing them to repopulate would fix it" ? Noter catalog can share the same name but every catalog has their own unique identifier (uuid) so deleting a catalog definition file will delete the uuid for this catalog, which can have repercussions in other library files

Comment: Hey Gorgious, thanks for the response! So I figured out the issue, I 'saved as' the problem files...and everything worked fine. My theory is the blend files hosting the assets were corrupted somehow.

My new blend files now populate with a full asset library and proper files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, the Blender files had been corrupted somehow. I saved my Assets as new Blend files....and everything worked fine